# Can't get raty plugin working - PHP

Tags: jquery, rating, raty

I've been having trouble getting raty star rating plugin working with PHP. When I run the function is just displays a text box with the value, but no stars! Here is my html... (I have a number of div's with the class 'star')

```
<div class="star" data-rating="3"></div>
```

And my function...

```
    function euroStarInit() {
    var star;
    $('.star').raty({
        path: '../library/images/',
        score: function () {
            return $(this).attr('data-rating');
        },
        readOnly: true,
        hints: '',
        noRatedMsg: ''
    });
}
```

This will just return a read only textbox with the value 3 in it. I have all the includes added correctly, I have the images in the correct directory, everything seem to be called correctly but just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong!!

Could someone please help me and point me in the right direction?!

Comment: Have you inspected the element? I suspect the rating images are added as part of inline stylesheet. Inspect it, and verify that it either creates an img-tag or applies the stylesheet, and that it actually points to the location of a valid image

Comment: Hi ole, ya i inspected the element, it displays <img>"&nbsp; repeated 5 times! I believe it should display the src of the image shouldn't it?

Comment: Well. I just tested your code, and theres nothing wrong with it per say. I'd check the console for any javascript errors.

Comment: Thanks Ole, I appreciate your help. I'l investigate this further and let you know how I get on.

Comment: I still can't figure out what i'm doing wrong here. I've stripped it right back and it's still not working. See code...
`code<div id="starId" class="star" data-number="3"></div>


<button href='#' onclick="testFunction()">Test</button>
<script type="text/javascript">

function testFunction(){
alert('1');
$('star').raty({
  number: function() {
    return $(this).attr('data-number');
  }
});
}
</script>` Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: $('star') should be $('.star')